# Is there a way to create a global CMakeLists file?

Tags: cmake

I downloaded an opensource project.[1](https://github.com/MimoMoreno/emotion-recognition)
It seems to have different folders and sub folders each of which has it's own CMakeLists.txt file.
If I have to run the application, will I have to generate a global CMakeLists.txt and then run it?
If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: Is there no top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, or some kind of readme explaining which CMakeList is a master one? Can you link to the project in question?

Comment: No, there isn't. @Angew, I edited my question to include the project.

Comment: " If I have to run the application, will I have to generate a global CMakeLists.txt and then run it? If yes, how do I do it?" - It fully up to the project. Ask the project's developer about that. (Well, we may try to **guess**, but: 1. Guessing contradicts to Stack Overflow intention. 2. Personally, I do not wish to play that guessing game if the project's author simply forgot to commit top-level `CMakeLists.txt`).